# JPA multiple ManyToOne with shared FK

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entitys with composite PK that share the same type (in below example it is  class **Shared**). Also I have 1 entity that creates releationship between Foo and Bar entitys. Here is example:

```
@Entity
class Shared {
    @Id private Long id;
}


@Entity
class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId private FooPK id;
}

@Embeddable
class FooPK implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="shared_id")
    private Shared shared;
    private Long fooId;
}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @EmbeddedId private BarPK id;
}

@Embeddable
class BarPK implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="shared_id")
    private Shared shared;
    private Long barId;
}

@Entity
class FooVsBar {
    @EmbeddedId private FooVsBarPK id;
}

@Embeddable
class FooVsBarPK implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="id_shared_foo", referencedColumnName="shared_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="id_foo", referencedColumnName="foo_id"),
    })
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="id_shared_bar", referencedColumnName="shared_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="id_bar", referencedColumnName="bar_id"),
    })
    private Bar bar;
}
```

This way `FooVsBar` table has 4 columns (2 FK's) but what I would like to achieve is to have 3 columns: `id_foo`, `id_bar` and `id_shared` as Foo and Bar will always be related to the same `Shared`. So there is no sense to repeat `id_shared`, it will be the same always.

**UPDATE**:
Here is UML how database is has to be. Unfortunately I can't alter tables, I just need to map JPA to this model.
[image]

Comment: Please start with a working, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Anyway, FooVsBar has only the two columns of FooVsBarPK.

Comment: There is 4 columns in FooVsBar table, id_shared_foo, id_foo, id_shared_bar and id_bar.

Comment: Ok, I seen that I can use @JoinTable but it is still need 4 columns instead 3.

Comment: Yes, there are four columns. It's not clear what you want or what your constraints are -- if you want to join all three tables with one join table then make three normal keys and one join table with a 3 key embeddedId -- if you have a parent with two children that have a many-to-many relationship then ignore the parent id in the join table. You should add a UML diagram or DDL that shows what you are trying to accomplish. As it is now there are too many ways to change your design or interpret your request to be able to make a sensible answer.

Comment: Please, check my update. This is how DB must be, so now I need to search solution to map it with JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
@Entity
class FooVsBar {
    @EmbeddedId private FooVsBarPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="shared_id", referencedColumnName="shared_id", 
                    insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="foo_id",
                    insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="shared_id", referencedColumnName="shared_id",
                    insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="bar_id",
                    insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Bar bar;
}

@Embeddable
class FooVsBarPK implements Serializable {

    private Long sharedId;

    private Long fooId;

    private Long barId;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this mapping cause DuplicateMappingException: Table [foo_vs_bar] contains physical column name [shared_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [shared_id], [sharedId]

Comment: If you set insertable and updatable to false as I did in my example, you shouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the solution was as in @Vlad Mihalcea example. Here is the complete code (getters and setters omitted):

```
@Entity
public class Shared {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BarPK id;

    @MapsId("sharedId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="shared_id")
    private Shared shared;
}

@Embeddable
public class BarPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="shared_id")
    private Long sharedId;

    @Column(name="bar_id")
    private Long barId;
}

@Entity
public class Foo {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooPK id;

    @MapsId("sharedId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="shared_id")
    private Shared shared;  
}

@Embeddable
public class FooPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="shared_id")
    private Long sharedId;

    @Column(name="foo_id")
    private Long fooId;
}

@Entity
public class FooVsBar {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooVsBarPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="shared_id", referencedColumnName="shared_id", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="foo_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="shared_id", referencedColumnName="shared_id", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="bar_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Bar bar;
}

@Embeddable
public class FooVsBarPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="shared_id")
    private Long sharedId;

    @Column(name="foo_id")
    private Long fooId;

    @Column(name="bar_id")
    private Long barId;
}
```